# React Native, State Changes, but Component Does not Properly Render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on my first React Native app, but feel very comfortable with React and React Native, which had me surprised regarding this snag.

Goal - Allow users to dynamically create tabs based on their input needs. Each tab reuses the same component which is a form. On press, the tab should display its corresponding form. The form works fine.

The Problem - The parent component won't render the correct form on tab press. The state updates, but the component remains on the first component selected. If I list the forms on one screen, one after the other, I can see that filling out one form, has no effect on the others (desired effect).

If I don't render a form component, it will work on the first tab press. This makes me wonder if React is not registering a change in the parent component because the child is always a copy of the other child components I desire displayed.

I approached this problem three ways with no luck.

1. Creating an array of components stored in the parent components state. Creating a new tab pushes a form component into the current array in state by grabbing that array, pushing a component into it and reseting state with that new array. I store a key in state that updates on a screen press. That key matches with an index in the component array to show the selected component with its corresponding tab.
2. Using componentDidUpdate to set a displayed component on the screen press similar to above, but instead of keying into the array in my render function, in the componentDidUpdate function manually setting a displayedView on each update of the component and using that in render.
3. Currently (code to follow) - Creating unique keys in state for each tab added that stores the corresponding component and using that to decipher which component to display.

I decided to put a ref on some child components. I used console.log before render to see if that correct component was being selected for display. It showed it was, but it was not appearing that way on the screen. I also added the tab number being clicked to the UI and I can see my state updating properly on each tab press.

Any help would be appreciated. Last resort I am going to have a user select the amount of forms they want before reaching this view and create it based on that number, but I would prefer not to.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import CreateWorkoutSet from './CreateWorkoutSet';
import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';

class CreateWorkout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      workoutSetTemplate0: <CreateWorkoutSet navigation={this.props.navigation}/>,
      showTab: 0,
      totalTabs: 0,
    }

    this.addWorkoutSetToGroup = this.addWorkoutSetToGroup.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      tabs: [
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ showTab: 0 })}>
          { this.state.showTab === 0 ? (
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 40, width: 40 }}>
              <Text>Tab: 1</Text>
            </View>
          ) :
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'grey', height: 40, width: 40 }}>
              <Text>Tab: 1</Text>
            </View>
          }
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ],
      showTab: 0
    })
  }

  addWorkoutSetToGroup() {
    let tabNumber = this.state.totalTabs + 1 
    let tabKey = `workoutSetTemplate${tabNumber}` 
    let tabs = this.state.tabs 
    tabs.push(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ showTab: tabNumber })}>
        { this.state.showTab === tabNumber ? (
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 40, width: 40 }}>
            <Text>Tab: {tabNumber}</Text>
          </View>
        ) : 
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'grey', height: 40, width: 40 }}>
            <Text>Tab: {tabNumber}</Text>
          </View>
        }
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
    this.setState({ [tabKey]: <CreateWorkoutSet navigation={this.props.navigation} />, tabs: tabs, totalTabs: tabNumber })
  }

  render() {
    let template = this.state[`workoutSetTemplate${this.state.showTab}`]
    let tabs = this.state.tabs
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 20}}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          {tabs}
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>Add Exercise To Group</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.addWorkoutSetToGroup()}>
            <Entypo name='circle-with-plus' size={36} color='red' />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View> 
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('BlockDetail')}>
          <Text>Blocks</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{this.state.showTab}</Text>
        {template}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default connect()(CreateWorkout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
this.forceUpdate()
```

after updating the state